# Creating a NotesdocumentCollection via View

Tags: lotusscript

I'm New in lotusscripting and it's kinda hard for me to figure things out. 
so.. i really do need your help.

I Have a notesview that has a Category, request type and names for the columns.. i need to sort them out by Category and request Type.

Here's my code for the creating a document collection.. i don't know if it's correct.

Request Type: Delete/Add
Category: "0001"

```
Set BadgeCol = badgeview.GetAllDocumentsByKey("Delete",False)
Call BadgeCol.PutAllInFolder("BDel")

Set Badgedoc = badgecol.GetFirstDocument()
```

I don't know whats next after this...

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dmytro pointed out the best way to do this, is to sort your view columns to do the sorting.

But be aware: `Set BadgeCol = badgeview.GetAllDocumentsByKey("Delete",False)` will alyways give you an unsorted collection. If you want to take advantage of the view  sorting, then you need to use a `NotesViewEntryCollection` instead of a `NotesDocumentCollection`. Both work almost the same in regards of cycling through them.

Your code might look like this then:

```
Dim BadgeCol as NotesViewEntryCollection
Dim badgeEntry as NotesViewEntry
Dim badgeDoc as NotesDocument

Set BadgeCol = badgeview.GetAllEntriesByKey("Delete",False)

Set badgeEntry = badgecol.GetFirstDocument()
While not badgeEntry is Nothing
  Set badgeDoc = badgeEntry.Document

  '- do whatever you need: Read items, create an array, whatever...

  Set badgeEntry = badgecol.GetNextDocument()
Wend
```

Comment: Thank Torsten! when i tried your code at the first database.. it works..but it doesnt return any value.. and when i try it on the other database.. i keep on getting an error.. is it really getFirstDocument? not GetFirstEntry?

I'm really really sorry.. this is my first time using lotusscript.. and i need to get a document of two databases. thank you!

Comment: Please open another thread with the exact question and the code causing your issue, comments are not good for debugging code...

Answer (score 2):

Here are few custom LotusScript solutions (there are no solutions provided by LotusScript)

- [How to sort a NotesDocumentCollection in Lotusscript](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2006/05/how-to-sort-notesdocumentcollection-in.html)
- [sortNotesDocumentCollection](http://per.lausten.dk/domino/sortNotesDocumentCollection.html)

However I would recommend you to sort view and than take documents from there.

[image]

However if LotusScript is a place where you want to sort collection you need to use your own sorting